# MySQL replace row values based on custom criteria

Tags: mysql, replace, sql-delete, sql-insert

I have a readings table with the following columns:

**ID, value, longitude, latitude, datatimestamp**

I always have new readings coming, so I need to do the followings:

1. If the new record has unique longitude & latitude pair, then
   insert a new record.
2. If the new record has a duplicate longitude
   & latitude pair in the table, then update 'value' and
   'datatimestamp'.

In every new batch, I have hundreds of records coming, so I'd like to use something like the REPLACE statement if possible, rather than DELETE and INSERT.

Please help. Thanks

Comment: I'm using MySQL Workbench

Answer (score 1):

1. Add an unique index on longitude, latitude
2. use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` syntax

See doc [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)

Comment: Thanks. I did what you suggested by adding a hash column (MD5 hash concatenating the long, lat columns). Then set that column as unique, then used the following query:

**INSERT INTO readings (val,gpslong,gpslat,datatime,readinghash) VALUES (66,'35.228555','32.225083','2015-09-09 19:37:15',md5(concat(netid,gpslong,gpslat)))
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE val=66,datatime='2015-09-09 19:37:15';**